# How do the opposite of infer in typescript (Advance typescript)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typing, typescript-types

I have dynamic table infrastructure. It in used in few projects all ready.
Lately i add some typescript feature to the table configuration.
Now i need to get some advance code (if it is not possible, let me know)
ok, the case is that i build object configuration to create a table.
And when the table need to represent User, the table configuration will help to fit the table with all typescript feature.

I try to make the code clear as i can to see the problem simple as it can...
In the configuration when i chose some component class i want the configuration object to know the key of the User the current cell represents and correctly add the User and the property key in the User that this cell represents to the Data interface Object this cell Component configuration gets
[online code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QCJzHAHgBVkBeZOEATwBpkBpZCAD0hABMNkBrCKgexjIS5XgKFEAfMgDeyAL4AoRaEixEKbPwQBXALYRwufMTIVqdRizacefQcLNiHU2YuTIM-AwCUIARx1gKAh2AAUofgAHaDAqAC5kAAoAN0SiAG16AF0ASjJpSipFJUUEABtMLnQsAGFvKP4QQzBTciLLJlZDW2cJJ3sJOmM4AFl+dghyrptqzBw8QiJLaXIahZNlhklpGXdkdkX9hCaMMCgdBDB+KCTD-ESR8cny-L2PDzAAC2AMADp7nAzID9kpShUqsgtLoDOB6npGs04ZUMBhiJ1rD0uH1HKJBsJhotnlMZliodp9C0RujtmZoZSjIsafQdqSOHM6g0mi1mYT8MTytI3B4APQAKjFnm8KBOk2QYpFJWUJxAZ2QJwR3KMwAQZne5JhLXhiKNKIwNH24slfxtyD0NxlXKRYC4CqVKnA0HgSGEVBixGkmPZyAAYjoQFdgE1hchmgB3JI2v5wKAAcwwiSKGTy6XdcRi6qdLQA8gAjABWbXMtAYbN6+JEdnEBKhda4cgyYmQoCbDnzEAcGpN2oQ2QAtAB+dJ+iAEdbGrVgaTyMz9wdFkerGMZACi3ZAvaE2GyU5jHjEiXoFo+yH7p53dBFIqYIH0nnOoFTt-4t6m0zjXw-r8t5fCg7BUCAcB6Dqhaas6+weICp7YLu2Rtr6-qgDA0DILU0gTsgT7IABhjIAIOjqoBWC3jOIHAXGwDlNMpYoN8YGLDRBZ9j8XBDouCG4eh84bq0HTVnQWE4dg+GtkR2DoiyxGMdM7A-mxyDlvwpbIKWOhgN2+m6NR0CRFAGACYkzQpNAFmxhA1lQKCJSdvix4ANzKmayAAKpYFAMY6H59KwmAxynOclzXLcgXQMFLSJHIXgGHF4ARNEsQJO+UCfgobwCd8vx-DFUApfp5DFaVTnguFv5nIkfHOmWla+dAdAAOQVRSIVtVu+r9okbWlQuzq1GabXXk2A2dYa4DjZaErdnZoQgex+DIFEkQxFAcTfvuFT8FgXD9lwBAtVANAdUFXUtD1HxuohiwJQJSUQH4gTBKEaVbXEiSpPkpDSCkE2is+PaAQ5yAAAZJBt6XbVQ+SldS4bcCA-BxiAdBWdAkh-C9b1BCE4SbRlv1pHZDn-YU1CQwJRGpvwcDTNDsPfQjBoMmA1Jne102cz1ePSgTH3E3DP3JOTZ0ZJdsXXbNeQFNWtMeEoIP7sg4M4SzJPw-kSGPHLXNMijaMY1j9k48rhHPgzTNQzDOtxHrizIYb3N+bzV0zWAPW0-IQA)

```
interface BaseData<T = any, K extends keyof T = keyof T> { }

interface DocumentData<T = any, K extends keyof T = keyof T> extends BaseData<T,K> {
  someRequiredProperty: (v: T[K]) => any
}

class BaseComponent<T = any, K extends keyof T = keyof T, DataModel extends BaseData<T, K> = BaseData<T, K>> {
  data
  constructor(data: DataModel) {
    this.data = data
  }
}

class DocumentComponentClass<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T, DataModel extends DocumentData<T, K> = DocumentData<T, K>> extends BaseComponent<T, K, DataModel>  {
  /** some code */
}

const componentDic = {
  DocumentComponentClass,
  /** ... more components */
}

interface Type<T> extends Function {
  new(...args: any[]): T
}

type componentObj<T = any, K extends keyof T = keyof T, D extends { [key in keyof typeof componentDic]-?: Type<BaseComponent> } = typeof componentDic> = {
  [E in keyof D]?: {
    key: K,
    type?: E, // enum string to tell who is the dynamic component
    data?: D[E] extends Type<infer C> ? // when you chose type this will be the data type of this component
      C extends BaseComponent<any, any, infer D> ?
          D // D<T,K> will do the job but it cuse errors
          : never
      : never
  }
}[keyof D];

class User {
  userDocument
  constructor(userDocument: { someDocumentProperty: string }) {
    this.userDocument = userDocument
  }
}

const test: componentObj<User, 'userDocument'> = {
  type: 'DocumentComponentClass',
  key: 'userDocument',
  /** i need the data property to incloses types <User,'userDocument'>   */
  data: {
    someRequiredProperty: (v) => v,
    // in hover `(property) DocumentData<unknown, never>.someRequiredProperty: (v: never) => any`
    // goal `(property) DocumentData<User, 'userDocument'>.someRequiredProperty: (v: User['userDocument']) => any`
  }
  // in hover `(property) data?: DocumentData<unknown, never>`
  // goal `(property) data?: DocumentData<User, 'userDocument'>`
}
```

Some type like this one that work will do it also, but the syntax's wrong

- these generics is unknown

```
type forceGenerics<T,G extends unknown[] = unknown[]> =T<G>
type forceGenerics2<D,G extends {} = any, GK extends keyof G> = D<G,GK>
```

Comment: What do you expect from `componentObj` ? Apart from that, generic argument `K` in `BaseData` is unused. It means that it does not affect type `DataModel` in `BaseComponent`, which in turn does not affect `DocumentComponentClass` type. Once you get rid of `K` in `BaseData` you will get an error in all your types. COuld you please minimize your example ? Also, just my opinion, using such amount of default values for generics does not look good. But, it is only my opinion, we all have different style of programming and different approaches. Try to split your case into several smaller

Comment: The real implementation look much like this one...
This is the simple it can be to understand the manipulation i try to do.
Yes, The K is unused and it exactly what I want to use but don't know how 
I want `infer D` to use it.
Thanks for the opinion, in the real code all generics types are necessary.

Comment: If generic is unused - you can't infer it from class implementation

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you, The only way to use this generic is to do something with it on the `infer D` like i write `D<T,K>` but it not the right syntax's, so the question is to find an alternative way.

Comment: Sorry, I might be mistaken. Just can't get around with expected result